# Sql query - selecting top 5 rows and further selecting rows only if User is present

Tags: sql, mysql

I kind of stuck on how to implement this query - this is pretty similar to the query I posted earlier but I'm not able to crack it.

I have a shopping table where everytime a user buys anything, a record is inserted.

Some of the fields are

```
* shopping_id (primary key)
* store_id
* user_id
```

Now what I need is to pull only the list of those stores where he's among the top 5 visitors:

When I break it down - this is what I want to accomplish:

```
* Find all stores where this UserA has visited
* For each of these stores - see who the top 5 visitors are.
* Select the store only if UserA is among the top 5 visitors.
```

The corresponding queries would be:

```
select store_id from shopping where user_id = xxx
```

```
select user_id,count(*) as 'visits' from shopping 
where store_id in (select store_id from shopping where user_id = xxx)
group by user_id
order by visits desc
limit 5
```

Now I need to check in this resultset if UserA is present and select that store only if he's present.
For example if he has visited a store 5 times - but if there are 5 or more people who have visited that store more than 5 times - then that store should not be selected.

So I'm kind of lost here.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.  It uses an intermediate VIEW to figure out how many times each user has shopped at each store.  Also, it assumes you have a stores table somewhere with each store_id listed once.  If that's not true, you can change `SELECT store_id FROM stores` to `SELECT DISTINCT store_id FROM shopping` for the same effect but slower results.

```
 CREATE VIEW shop_results (store_id, user_id, purchase_count) AS
     SELECT store_id, user_id, COUNT(*)
     FROM shopping GROUP BY store_id, user_id

 SELECT store_id FROM stores 
    WHERE 'UserA' IN 
      (SELECT user_id FROM shop_results 
       WHERE shop_results.store_id = stores.store_id 
       ORDER BY purchase_count DESC LIMIT 5)
```

You can combine these into a single query by placing the SELECT from the VIEW inside the sub-query, but I think it's easier to read this way and it may well be true that you want that aggregated information elsewhere in the system — more consistent to define it once in a view than repeat it in multiple queries.

Comment: Thanks Larry - I do have the stores table but that contains info only about the store like address name etc. So I ill have to change it to SELECT DISTINCT store_id FROM shopping. Also if I want to combine into a single query - is this how it will look:
<pre>
SELECT store_id FROM stores 
    WHERE 'UserA' IN 
      (SELECT store_id, user_id, COUNT(*) from shopping 
       WHERE shopping.store_id = stores.store_id 
       group by store_id, user_id
       ORDER BY purchase_count DESC LIMIT 5)
</pre>
Thanks

Comment: Also Mysql throws an error saying - This version of Mysql does not support Limit in subquery - I'm using Mysql version 5